# RecyclerView scroll up is not smooth when the height isn't fixed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As stated in the question, I have a RecyclerView that displays images of different height.

The ImageView's height is initially 0dp and the width is match_parent, but in BindViewHolder I set the height to the correct value.

It works fine if you scroll down the list, but when you scroll back up:
As the previous ViewHolder is drawn it's height is initially set to something like 40dp as the image isn't loaded yet, but then suddenly it jumps to 400 as the new height is set to the ImgeView, which makes it very jittery and not smooth at all.

I tried prefetching and caching, but nothing worked.

Should I use ListView and load images on-demand knowing that the number of displayed items will reach 1000, or what can I do?

The is the ViewHolder layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="8dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:layout_margin="8dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.davemorrissey.labs.subscaleview.SubsamplingScaleImageView
        android:id="@+id/post_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is OnBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val target: SimpleTarget<File> = object: SimpleTarget<File>() {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: File, transition: Transition<in File>?) {
            thumbnail.setImage(ImageSource.uri(Uri.fromFile(resource)).tilingEnabled())
        }
    }
    if (post?.url?.endsWith(".jpg", true) == true|| post?.url?.endsWith(".png", true) == true) {
        thumbnail.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        thumbnail.recycle()
        thumbnail.setDoubleTapZoomDuration(300)
        if(post.preview != null) {
            thumbnail.post {
                val scale: Float = post.preview.images[0].source.height.toFloat()/post.preview.images[0].source.width.toFloat()
                val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = thumbnail.layoutParams
                layoutParams.height = (thumbnail.measuredWidth.toFloat() * scale).toInt()
                thumbnail.layoutParams = layoutParams
                glide.downloadOnly().load(post.preview.images[0].source.url).into(target)
            }
        }
    } else {
        thumbnail.visibility = View.GONE
        glide.clear(target)
        thumbnail.recycle()
    }
    }
}
```

Where thumbnail is a [SSIV](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

Comment: Could you paste code. E.g. Adapter class and ViewHolders

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: what is the like the range of the heights of these images? do they vary a lot?
could you try to have a placeholder image with a default size and replace it onResourceReady()?

Comment: It varies a lot the scale could really be 0.1 or 10.
I tried setting the height to 400dp to be close to how tall they will be, it made things a little better, but still jittery.

Comment: Nevermind I found the soultion, I'll post an answer.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I got the measured width asynchronously every time, which caused a delay in setting the height.

I calculated measuredHeight on OnCreateViewHolder and store it for later use.